# How to run a server in the cloud

Tags: python, http, server, cloud

Im creating a server in Python that receives POST requests, process the information in the request using some scripts (sometimes using a database) and send back a answer in JSON format. Im searching for a way to run this server and code in the cloud, in a way that i dont need my PC turned on for it to work, because my connection is very unstable.

Comment: Your question is off topic here. But: [Virtual private server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server)

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of web hosting companies out there, you just need to find the one that is right for you.

My personal favorite for python apps is [heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python), but there are many out there. AWS is another popular one.

In future when asking questions, try to do more research before hand, and try to be more specific with questions. It would have been useful to know what kind of database you are using, or whether you're using flask or django.

Comment: I did a lot of research, 3 days of research actually. I use HTTPServer in python and MySQL database